# Discord command invoke error, no such table logs when there is

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

im trying to create a discord bot which can have commands which can be chosen in multiple servers. im creating a logging command, that logs events like kicks/bans, and message deletes. Ive added # lines so i can understand which line does what. My code is below:

```
import discord.ext
import sqlite3
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime #for commands later in my project
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=",", intents=discord.Intents.all())

conn = sqlite3.connect('logs.db')
c = conn.cursor()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user}')

@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    # Create a new channel called "log" in the guild
    log_channel = await guild.create_text_channel('log')
    print(f'Created log channel in {guild.name}')

    # Set up permissions for the bot and the guild members
    await log_channel.set_permissions(guild.me, send_messages=True)
    await log_channel.set_permissions(guild.default_role, send_messages=False)

    # Save the channel ID to the database
    c.execute('INSERT INTO logs (guild_id, channel_id) VALUES (?, ?)',
              (guild.id, log_channel.id))
    conn.commit()

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    # Retrieve the log channel ID from the database based on the guild ID
    c.execute('SELECT channel_id FROM logs WHERE guild_id = ?', (member.guild.id,))
    log_channel_id = c.fetchone()[0]

    # Send the kick message to the log channel
    log_channel = client.get_channel(log_channel_id)
    await log_channel.send(f'{member} has been kicked from the server.')

@client.event
async def on_member_ban(guild, user):
    # Retrieve the log channel ID from the database based on the guild ID
    c.execute('SELECT channel_id FROM logs WHERE guild_id = ?', (guild.id,))
    log_channel_id = c.fetchone()[0]

    # Send the ban message to the log channel
    log_channel = client.get_channel(log_channel_id)
    await log_channel.send(f'{user} has been banned from the server.')

@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    # Retrieve the log channel ID from the database based on the guild ID
    c.execute('SELECT channel_id FROM logs WHERE guild_id = ?', (message.guild.id,))
    log_channel_id = c.fetchone()[0]

    # Send the message delete message to the log channel
    log_channel = client.get_channel(log_channel_id)
    await log_channel.send(f'A message by {message.author} has been deleted: {message.content}')

@client.command()
async def log(ctx, *, message):
    # Retrieve the log channel ID from the database based on the guild ID
    c.execute('SELECT channel_id FROM logs WHERE guild_id = ?', (ctx.guild.id,))
    log_channel_id = c.fetchone()[0]

    # Send the logging message to the log channel
    log_channel = client.get_channel(log_channel_id)
    await log_channel.send(f'{ctx.author} said: {message}')



client.run('token')
```

My files look like this:

[image]

Ive tried re working the code multiple times over the last few hours trying out new commands using databases, but i get the same error every time:

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: OperationalError: no such table: logs

Im not quite sure where ive gone wrong and ive browsed other stack overflow problems regarding no such table errors but none of the solutions worked (already tried hard coding the path of the database but got the same error)

Comment: HI. This is not a discord error, but an error with the table. Have you created it?

Comment: Yeah i linked an image you can see it in my files